# How do you override the stat width in git pull?

Tags: git

When running `git log`, you can specify eg `--stat=180` to override the width of the stats graph. `git pull` has a `--stat` option but it doesn't take a width.

Context: I'm calling `git pull` over ssh in a cron job. It falls back to a default width of 80, which isn't what I want. There's no tty, so I can't set the width with `stty`.

Answer (score 0):

Option `--stat` takes no value in `git pull` but you can use a different command like `git diff`. You need to write down the current head commit, run `git pull` and then `git diff --stat`:

```
prev_commit=`git rev-parse HEAD`
git pull
git diff --stat=180 $prev_commit
```